# How to make all Google products appear in English?

Tags: google-account, google, localization

Most of my accounts on various Google products are on English, but some consistently appear on my native tongue, Croatian (for example, Webmaster tools). I don't like this inconsistency, and would like everything to be on English.

Is there some central place when I can make this happen by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your browser’s main content language to English.

- [Chrome](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1059490)
- [Firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/settings-fonts-languages-pop-ups-javascript#w_languages)
- [Opera](http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/en/language.html)

Comment: Done that, but I doubt that affects things, as some are still shown in Croatian.

Comment: My main language is set to English with no mention of Czech but now everything is in Czech for me (I do live in Czech Republic). Really hate when Google tries to second-guess me. I want a global language setting for all Google properties and in my case I want to be able to set everything in English.

Answer (score 2):

By luck I found it! Here you can set your language settings for when you login to Google.com:

https://www.google.com/preferences

This is a big usability bug in Google. Maybe they don't understand that if you write "Settings" in a language I don't know I'm never gonna figure it out even if you put it right in front of my face! Excuse the rant.