# How to change google applications language?

Tags: google, localization

I used to live in Brazil. But I'm now back in France (my country) and I would like to have google webs apps in French.

When I log in to google from a French computer, google sets the language to Brazilian Portuguese (for all google apps). It's a big issue because I can't change it afterwards. Every person who use google in this computer has to do it in Portuguese. Cleaning cache and cookies does not change anything. Google must use the IP address to guess language. At a moment (several weeks after my log) google change finally the language.

I would like to know how to set manually the language for google apps and disable google automatic language guess.

Comment: [Change the google interface language](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40881)

Comment: [How to make all Google products appear in English?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/30893)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your language in the [Accounts settings](https://www.google.com/accounts) (in the Language section, and then don't forget to reload your browser) and in the [Search settings](http://www.google.com/preferences#languages).